# Connection to/from Pi 2 very slow

Tags: pi-2, networking

When I first received my Pi 2 model B and got everything installed, I was able to browse the file contents remotely from another computer pretty quickly. This also went for game scraping in RetroPie.

Now, for whatever reason, remote file browsing (either from windows explorer or filezilla) is very slow, if it even lets me connect at all. This is also the same for game scraping. It will attempt to scrape game info but act like it is hung up and not do anything. I've even tried scraping one game to see if it was a bulk scrape issue, but with the same results.

Yesterday I re-formatted my micro SD card (which is a Sandisk SDHC class 10 16gb) to see if I screwed something up in a settings menu, but even during the fresh install it was still acting the same.

Does anyone have any suggestions to what might be causing this? I've ran the command **ifconfig eth0** to see if the port is showing any errors, but it does not.

Comment: You haven't actually said how the Pi is connected to your remote PC.

Comment: @joan either through windows explorer or filezilla... open a windows explorer window and put the ip of the PI in the address bar: \\192.168.2.120 or an SFTP connection through Filezilla

Comment: Is this a direct Ethernet link between the two machines?

Comment: @joan No, my remote PC is on a wireless connection to my router, the Pi is wired to router.

Comment: So connect them direct to rule out the router or wireless as the problem.